# Run trigger script when a one or more cells change in a range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to google sheets & script app.  I'm using google sheets to maintain real-time project budgets.  I've created a history tab to capture historical high level information (project code, category, Total Approved Budget, Projected Cost, Date stamp).  Each time the scrip runs, it captures 4 rows of data.

```
function recordHistory() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('ForMaster');
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('History');
  var data = sheet1.getRange('S84:W87').getValues();
  var last_row = sheet2.getLastRow();

  sheet2.getRange(last_row + 1,1,4,5 ).setValues(data);
}
```

I'd like to set up a trigger that runs where ever there is a change to any of the cells in data range (S84:W87).

I've tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
function setupTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('recordHistory')
  .forSpreadsheet('1TSX27lzmOpv6P8Z8zJJhYem_yLQwP-gYK4WYHJ3LEuA')
  .onEdit()
  .create();
}

function recordHistory(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('ForMaster');
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('History');
  var data = sheet1.getRange('S84:W87').getValues();
  var last_row = sheet2.getLastRow();
  
  sheet2.getRange(last_row + 1,1,4,5 ).setValues(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

You don't need an installable trigger since you don't use any service that requires permission.

- You can use a simple `onEdit(e)` trigger instead.

In order to define the range `S84:W87` that you would like to accept edits, you can do that:

`row>=84 && row <= 87 && col >=19 && col <=23`

`84` is the starting row, `87` is the end row, column `19` is `S` and column `23` is `W`.

Also you want to only accept edits on the sheet `ForMaster`.

Therefore the `if` statement would look like that:

`if(as.getName()=="ForMaster" && row>=84 && row <= 87 && col >=19 && col <=23)`

### Solution:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const ss = e.source;
  const as = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const col = e.range.getColumn(); 
  if(as.getName()=="ForMaster" && row>=84 && row <= 87 && col >=19 && col <=23){
     const sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('History');
     const data = as.getRange('S84:W87').getValues();
     const last_row = sheet2.getLastRow();
     sheet2.getRange(last_row + 1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
  }
}
```

**Note that!**

- The `onEdit` triggers are triggered upon **user** edits. This function won't be triggered by formula nor another script.
- Again, this is a trigger function. You are **not** supposed to execute it manually and you will actually get errors. All you have to do is to **save** this code snippet to the script editor and then it will be triggered automatically upon edits.

Comment: That's worked like a charm!  Thanks Marios